# Unexpected type error using numpy.save (and savez)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, io

I am attempting to use numpy's [`savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) and [`load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) methods to (surprise) save and load numpy arrays which are large enough that the method I was using previously (saving as JSON) are noticeably slow.

I have reproduced the problem I encountered in the following code snippet:

```
import numpy

test_path = "test.npy"
test_data = numpy.random.rand(100000)

with open(test_path, 'w') as test_file:
    numpy.save(test_file, test_data)
```

When run, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I have been able to work around this by instead passing `numpy.save` the path directly as a string:

```
numpy.save(test_path, test_data)
```

**However, I find this error odd as according to my reading of the documentation, `numpy.save` should accept an open file-like object directly. Am I missing something?**

Comment: You need to open the file as `wb`.  `save` writes bytes, not unicode str.  But why would you want to open the file yourself?  Isn't it simpler to let `np.save` do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file and then saving it to that file that you opened, `numpy.save` does not need the file pointer that points to the opened file, but the path to the file, so the code should be,

```
numpy.save(test_path, test_data)
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, this is what I ended up doing. My question is not what I can do to fix it, but why the code snippet I provided behaves as it does, given that the documentation explicitly states that `numpy.save` can be passed a file-like object

Comment: ok just checked the numpy code, as far as i can see this should not happen, and should just work but for some reason it does not as something called as the header_prefix is byte, which they are making using their own magic module which returns a bytes, so i think its a code issue, not sure though maybe someone smarter than me will be able to explain this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open(test_path, 'wb+') as test_file:
    numpy.save(test_file, test_data)
```

Since .npy is a binary file, you have to pass your data as bytes not a string.